# Writing an xslt function that only changes the value of an xml node if the value is boolean

Tags: xml, xslt

My current working XSLT solution looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="something" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
            <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='Foo']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns:bar(.)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
        
        <xsl:function name="ns:bar">
            <xsl:param name="foo"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$foo = 'true'">Y</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$foo = 'false'">N</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$foo = '1'">Y</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$foo = '0'">N</xsl:when>    
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$foo"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

where the `ns:bar` function grabs an XML element of `<Foo></Foo>` and converts the possible boolean value into a string. However, some of my XMLs already have a non-boolean value and as such, don't need to be changed. Is there a way that I could restrict the XSLT to only process Foo if Foo is a boolean value? Casting Foo using the boolean function won't work because a `<Foo>Y<Foo>` and `<Foo>N</Foo>` will both evaluate to true, and trying to pass an empty string will throw an error.

Comment: Would using `//*[local-name()='Foo'][. castable as xs:boolean]` in the match template suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Foo' and . castable as xs:boolean]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="if (. = ('true', '1')) then 'Y' else 'N'"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that you even don't need any separate function (*ns:bar* in
your code sample).
As *castable* matches only elements with *boolean* content, it is
enough to check only for *true* and *1* (then output *'Y'*).
Otherwise output *'N'*).

As this script uses *xs* namespace, you must include *xmlns:xs="..."* in *xsl:stylesheet* tag.

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/pP7Nbzt

Comment: Why not simply `<xsl:value-of select="if (.) then 'Y' else 'N'"/>`.

Comment: Change to *if (.)* would cause that each non-empty string is treated as *true*,
even if it contains e.g. *false* or *N*.

Comment: Right. It should be `if (xs:boolean(.))` or `if (. cast as xs:boolean)`. Otherwise why filter only the castable.

Comment: So trying the solution above, it tries to evaluate 'true' as a string, but after changing the code to  `<xsl:value-of select="if (. = (true())) then 'Y' else 'N'"/>`  the solution worked!